# APK file size increased after using kotlin in Android Project

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I've created an Android application in android studio and for programming language I used **Kotlin**.
Now my application finished and I want to build my app, but after building the app, my APK file size becomes **35mb** !!!
My **drawable folders** size is **2mb** and I dont have any large size files, but why my application size is **35mb** ?!

For generating test apk version, I used **Build -> Generate Signed Build/APK** from android studio menu.

But when I use **java** for language this size is **7mb**!!!

**I used these dependencies :**

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidx_version"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$androidx_version"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constrant_layout_version"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$material_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material_version"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$material_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junit_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidx_junit_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso_version"
    //Anko lib
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
    //Rx
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxandroid_version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxjava_version"
    //OkHttp
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp_version"
    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.5.0'
    //Gson
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gson_version"
    //Image
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"
    //Calligraphy
    implementation "io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:$calligraphy_version"
    implementation "io.github.inflationx:viewpump:$viewpump_version"
    //Preferences lib
    implementation "com.github.MrNouri:GoodPrefs:$nourilib_versions"
    //Dynamic ui sizes
    implementation "com.github.MrNouri:DynamicSizes:$nourilib_versions"
    //Support MultiDex
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
    //Animations
    implementation "com.daimajia.easing:library:$yoyoanimation_version"
    implementation "com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:$nineoldandroid_version"
    //Map
    implementation "ir.map.sdk:sdk_map:$mapir"
    implementation "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:$mapbox_service"
    implementation "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-geojson:$mapbox_service"
    implementation "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:$mapbox_telemetry"
    implementation "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-gestures:$mapbox_gestures"
    //Permission
    implementation "ru.superjob:kotlin-permissions:$permission_version"
    //Expandable recyclerview
    implementation "com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:$expandable_recycler_version"
    //Firebase messaging
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebase_messaging_version"
    //Firebase crashlytics
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:$firebase_analytics_version"
    implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$firebase_crashlytics_version"
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: check assets and lib folders in your apk file.

Comment: are you convert your project java to kotlin?

Comment: @feridok, i have just 2 fonts

Comment: @ViralPatel, not. from first i used kotlin!

Comment: what about libs?

Comment: @feridok, i haven't any lib folder. i just use above dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you are using lots of library might be this is reason for big app size.
Few thing you can to reduce app size

1. Use your own component other then external library
   for example you are using Expendable recyclerview library 
   `implementation"com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:$expandable_recycler_version"`
2. Use Svg drawable other then png etc .Because you can use same svg file all screen size .
3. Remove unused resources
4. And last if you tried all of this then Use `ABI` . Though this you can create multi build for different device.
   Paste this in `android` block in build.gradle file

   ```
   splits {
    abi {
       enable true
       reset()
       include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi', 'mips',
      'mips64'
       universalApk true
      }
     }
     project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 
     3, 'mips': 5, 'mips64': 6, 'x86': 8, 'x86_64': 9]

     android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

     variant.outputs.each { output -> output.versionCodeOverride =
     project.ext.versionCodes.get(
       output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0
       ) * 1000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
     }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Drag and Drop apk file in android studio. you will see analyzer of apk. and see individual size taken by all libs, image and java files etc.

Comment: thanks, but can you send to me link for tutorial for this?

Comment: read this two blog official android and medium . you will learn how to use apk analyzer.

1) https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer
2) https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/making-the-most-of-the-apk-analyzer-c066cb871ea2

Comment: ya this link (https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/making-the-most-of-the-apk-analyzer-c066cb871ea2) has everything related to it.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Build > Analyze APK > Select your APK.

You can see which file made your app size too BIG.

[image]

---

**UPDATE 1 :**

Do these changes in your `build.gradle(Module:app)` file. It decreases the APK size almost (40-50)%.

```
    android {
    // Other settings

      buildTypes {
          release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please see this link : http://uupload.ir/files/p42q_screen_shot_1398-09-26_at_10.09.27.jpg . in analyze show me **13Mb** but after build show me **29Mb**

Answer (score 0):

You can fix these errors by analyzing the generated APK.

In Android Studio -> Build => Analyse APK.

Select the Generated APK from file system and see what resources are bloating up your APK.

[image]

Please let me know if you have any further doubts.

Comment: Please see this link : http://uupload.ir/files/p42q_screen_shot_1398-09-26_at_10.09.27.jpg . in analyze show me **13Mb** but after build show me **29Mb**

Comment: Well, got your issue. This issue happens when any of the dependencies you use are jni specific code ( many of the ML related libraries like image processing, google image vision etc..) so those libraries have libso files that will be generated for each CPU architecture. so the bloating in the size is because it is generating the libso for each of the architecture.

Comment: Ways to solve:

1. Check the libraries which are generating the libso files and if those features are optional remove that library.

2. If they are really important and if your app is being distributed via playstore, Use App Bundles it will make sure that your app will be optimized specific to the device( also use proguard for code obfuscation & shrinking)

Hope This helps!

Answer (score 0):

As @Soham Suggest Analyze your APK moreover you can shrink your Code, Resource , apply Obfuscation and Optimize your code.

here is the link for official documentation [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)

Comment: Please see this link : http://uupload.ir/files/p42q_screen_shot_1398-09-26_at_10.09.27.jpg . in analyze show me **13Mb** but after build show me **29Mb**

Answer (score 0):

If your project `minSdkVersion` is 18 or higher, then you can compress your PNG, JPEG and BMP by converting them to WebP format.

First step is ,Control-click the drawable that you want to convert and select Convert to WebP. Then, Select Skip images when the encoded result is larger than the original and click OK to convert the image.

**Remove unused resources**

Gradle can automatically remove resources on your behalf if you enable `shrinkResources` in your app's `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    // Other settings

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Follow this two things to reduced size of your apk. Please share your  `Analyze APK`  screenshot,if need help .

I hope it'll help you..!